# Remove first position of List NameValuePair

Tags: android

Hi all I have a List where I add parameters, whcih I use to connect and do operations in a MySQL with the help of PHP script. The PHP script expects a "id", which is a int that retrieves from Android app. However, although I send the intent with the correct id the List NameValuePairs converts it to a especific format in this case. For example, if the id is `2` the final params will be `id=2`, which is a String that the PHP script does not understand. I would like to know if there is a way of removing the first characters and instead of `id=2`, only send `2`.

Here is the code I use

```
 public void monitorizar() throws Exception{

    try {
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));

    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_detalles, "GET", params);
    Log.d("params", String.valueOf(params));
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> temp;
    temp = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

Obviously, when I send the params to the php script, it gives me an error because the id is not an integer and it is written with this format id="id".

Comment: Also 'String.valueOf(params));' doesn't look right. params is a list, not a String.

Comment: Where is id declared?

Comment: id is obtained from the list, but I have made changes also declaring it myself with ints appering in the database

Comment: Without the id declared in Android, and the php script where you read it out, we cannot help you.